# OSX Yosemite + Crossover (Wine) = Sporadic MIDI Sync

Tags: macos, audio, usb, midi, wine

The setup:
OSX Yosemite.
Ableton Live 9 (Suite).
Crossover/Wine (14.0.3).
Connected device is a Novation Launchpad Mini (USB).

The problem:
The install of Ableton and most of its use work well. I have compiled and successfully installed wineasio.dll (wineasio.dll.so) to obtain low latency audio, again this works extremely well.

But what I am finding is the communication between the LP and Live is somewhat sporadic. examples of this are, having to list the LP in the midi in/out section of live multiple times just to get it to behave correctly (mostly), pads/lights randomly lighting/becoming non responsive, active tracks not showing (lighting up)

There is no pattern in all this. bug what i can say this setup works without problems in windows and OSX (obviously)

before you ask I'm having to use WINE as one of my favourite VST's is only windows based.

if someone can recommend a VM based solution (with low latency audio/ Midi) i will welcome it.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: That was very helpful thanks. Hopefully I'll be able to get the answer I was looking for. Good day.